# Android WebView Default Context Menu

Tags: android, android-webview

Easy question for you Android guys.

I've implemented an Activity with a single WebView, and it's working fine.

My question is: **Does the WebView come with a Default Context Menu (onLongClick) to make actions like "share link" or "download picture"?**

I don't want to build the whole context menu for those actions. I rather use a default one.
Have I missed a WebView.getSettings() setting to enable the default context menu to be used?

Answer (score 1):

> Does the WebView come with a Default Context Menu (onLongClick) to make actions like "share link" or "download picture"?

AFAIK, no. Those are features of a Web browser, not of `WebView`. I think the only contextual operations for `WebView` come with text selection (copy, etc.).

Comment: Thanks. That's what I thought. I'm afraid I will have to implement a custom context menu.